# What is production tooling?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Define "production tooling"?
What are its advantages?
And why production tooling is essential for manufacturing?

Comment: This looks like an assignment or homework...

Comment: This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: yes.. its my assignment and I have put the same question here... actually I want to ask, Define "Production tooling". and types of production tooling?

Comment: Please update your question to match your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are to make one part or only samples, you would have prototype tooling.

If you are to mass produce a part(high volume), then you have production tooling. Depending on your budget and quantity to be mass produced, it will drive the design of the production tooling.

The considerations for production tooling are as follows but not limited to:

1. Quantity to be made before service is required
2. Setup
3. Serviceability
4. Mistake proofing/human factors
5. Safety
6. List item
7. Quality
8. Process Monitoring/inspection system
9. Speed of production
10. Budget

Your question is vague, so I don't know what you are to manufacture, but apply the above points.

Production Tooling is the tools used to mass
Produce a product. Production tooling considers the above points when being designed and manufactured.

Comment: actually question is what is production tooling??? just definition...

Comment: @TalhaRazzaq see updated answer. Production tooling considers the points I listed when being made to use for high volume production.

Comment: In production tooling, what we supposed to do,  Do we make a pattern or anything else??

Comment: @TalhaRazzaq I don't know what you are making...there are many methods and techniques specific to certain products. What are you making? This seems like a separate question

Comment: We are not making anything. this a theoretical question..

Comment: @TalhaRazzaq Then, in theory, can you answer the 10 points in my answer? Do you need a hypothetical product?

Comment: yes that will be acceptable..